# How to show in list Facebook returned Json data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, facebook

i have json in object.

```
 {
"data": [
{
  "name": "Diljeet Jamwal", 
  "uid": 553042280, 
  "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/274654_553042280_2105727599_q.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "Jatinder Sharma", 
  "uid": 553042280, 
  "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/274654_553042280_2105727599_q.jpg"
}]}
```

i want to show this in list in C#, how to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string data in yourlist)
{
console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Of course do the parsing job to fill your list before ;)

Comment: i think you don't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try Newtonsoft.Json library http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Example:

```
String yourdata = "..."  // your JSON response

JObject json = JObject.Parse(yourdata);
```

after this, you can access your data:

```
String name = json["data"][0]["name"] //it should be Diljeet Jamwal
```

Comment: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Can you check that your response is valid JSON. I checked in sample app using your posted response, and it's working

Comment: we have our json in a object

Comment: then we use 
JObject json = JObject.Parse(yourdata.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

thanks  to all, i have done this

```
 dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.ToString());
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            foreach (var name in item["data"])
            {
                Response.Write(name["name"]);
            }
        }
```

using this